# Finding last digits with modulo from a million digits int; need an explanation?

Tags: python, modulo, counting, largenumber

Lets say I have a random million digit number = x, such that:

```
len(str(x)) = 1000000
```

From looking at some explanations I can use  x % (10 ** n) to find the last n digits. But I can't wrap my head around why that works.

Such that if I wanted to find the last 11 digits of x my code would be:

```
x % (10 ** 11)
```

Could someone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Do you understand how the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) works?

Answer (score 6):

Think of it this way:

- If you want to find the last digit of a number, you can divide it by 10, and the remainder of the division will be the last digit of the number.
- If you want to find the last 2 digits of a number, you can divide it by 100, and the remainder of the division will be the last 2 digits of the number.
- If you want to find the last 3 digits of a number, you can divide it by 1000, and the remainder of the division will be the last 3 digits of the number.
- If you want to find the last *n* digits of a number, you can divide it by 10**n, and the remainder of the division will be the last *n* digits of the number. In mathematical terms, the last `n` digits of number `x` are given by:

  ```
  x % (10 ** n)
  ```

In case you don't know, the modulo operator (%) divides two numbers and *returns the remainder*.

Answer (score 2):

`%` returns the remainder after division, just like in primary school when you learned long division. So `7%3 = 1`.  I guess you know that `**` is exponentiation, so `10**3 = 1000`. Your example `x % (10**11)` divides `x` by `10**11` and tells you the remainder. That must be the digits left over once you take away the largest possible multiple of `10**11`, in other words the last `n` digits.

Comment: I think your answer is correct, but it's difficult to understand, the way you wrote it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I exigently endeavor to ameliorate comprehensibility :)